# Насколько умны/глупы компиляторы

Tags: ассемблер

Как реализовать задание:

> Доказать насколько умны компиляторы путем написания простых блоков оператор, написать ассемблерную версию компилятора

Или где можно прочитать о способе реализации?

```
1) A = 2+3


2) if |A>B| op1
       else    op2



3) for (int i=0, i<10, i+1)
         op3
```

Доказать, насколько глупы компиляторы, подставив во втором пункте значения:

```
5 > 3
```

В третьем пункте подставить:

```
i = 5, i < 3
```

Comment: Компиляторы не бывают умными и глупыми.. Умными (и не очень) бывают *авторы языков* (трансляцию которых осуществляют компиляторы (с большим или меньшим *количеством ошибок*))

Comment: Согласен с Вами, это тоже правда. Не подскажете, как мне исследовать возможности компилятора(особенности, которые заложили его авторы)?(книжку, статью) как все это делается

Answer (score 3):

В комментарий, отвечающий на *`"Не подскажете, как мне исследовать возможности компилятора(особенности, которые заложили его авторы)?(книжку, статью) как все это делается"`*) не помещается, поэтому пишу в ответе.

Честно говоря, литературу посвященную именно *исследованиям возможностей* компилятора, не знаю, но вот что в принципе могу посоветовать по теме компиляторов.

Для общего знакомства с языками на мой взгляд хороша книга -- ["Языки программирования: разработка и реализация" Т. Пратт, М. Зелковиц](https://www.livelib.ru/book/1000459727/about-yazyki-programmirovaniya-razrabotka-i-realizatsiya-t-pratt).

Говоря непосредственно о компиляторах, безусловно, следует отметить классический труд, называемый ["Книгой дракона"](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B:_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%8B,_%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B8_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B) (в сети легко можно найти ее текст). Вероятно, для практического вхождения в тему стоит почитать [Креншоу Д. "Пишем компилятор"](http://alexei-s1.narod.ru/books/pishem_compilator.pdf).

Для знакомства с устройством процессора (системой команд, а также немного с ассемблером) посмотрите, например, ["Цифровая схемотехника и архитектура компьютера"](http://easyelectronics.ru/files/Book/digital-design-and-computer-architecture-russian-translation.pdf). Понятно, что для каждой конкретной реализации потребуется проштудировать Programmer Rererence Manual по его ISA (instruction set architecture).

И несомненно, надо рекомендовать практику компиляции примеров в ассемблерный код (например, запуская `gcc -S -O2 t.c; less t.s`) с различными ключами оптимизации (см., скажем [man gcc](https://linux.die.net/man/1/gcc)), а также непосредственного экспериментирования с измерением времени работы своих примеров.

Comment: `практику компиляции примеров в ассемблерный код` - что сейчас очень удобно делать на [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org), если надо просто посмотреть на результирующий код.